# In pandas, how can I select the second row, unless there is only one row (in which case that row should be returned)?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with `n` rows.

I want to select the second row, except when there is only one row I want that row.

Here are some dummy data:

```py
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(range(20,28),columns=["day"])
df.sort_values("day",ascending=True,inplace=True)
df
```

Things I have tried:

```py
df.head(2).tail(1)
```

This fails for `n` = 1 - e.g.

```py
df.head(1).iloc[1]
```

> IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Thanks as ever

Comment: I think you could do simple if else.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
row = df.iloc[min(len(df), 2)-1]
```

Output:

```
day    21
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Note that `df.head(2).tail(1)` should also always work, do you have issues with it?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df.iloc[1] if len(df) > 1 else df.iloc[0]
```

If need one row DataFrame:

```
df.iloc[[1]] if len(df) > 1 else df.iloc[[0]]
```

Solution without `if-else` is get second row and multiple by condition - if True, select first row:

```
for i in range(1,5):
    df = df2.head(i)
    
    df1 = df.iloc[1 * (len(df) > 1)]
    #ig again call Head and tail it working too
    #df1 = df.head(2).tail(1)
    print (df1)
    
day    20
Name: 0, dtype: int64
day    21
Name: 1, dtype: int64
day    21
Name: 1, dtype: int64
day    21
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Why do you need a `1*` AND `int`?

Comment: @jtlz2 - You are right, not necessary

Answer (score 0):

This works if you consider

```
for i in range(1,5):
    print(df.head(i).iloc[:2].iloc[-1].day)
```

This should print:

```
20
21
21
21
```

which is what you (I) were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

We can write a condition to check the length 
and then we can use iloc to query it

iloc syntax - iloc[Rows,Column]

```
if len(df)>1:#if more than 1 rows
    print(df.iloc[1,:])# It will print 2nd row and all the columns
else:
    print(df.iloc[-1,:]) # if only 1 row it will print the last row
```

[image: when only 1 row]

[image: When more than 2 rows]

Answer (score 0):

I would use a plain and simple try/except block like the following

```
try:
   row = df.iloc[1]
except IndexError:
   row = df.iloc[0]
```